# Find all missing letters in string (string is in alphabetical order)

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I'm trying to create a function that finds all missing characters in the string and returns all the missing letters (**the string will be in alphabetical order**).

For example findMissing('abcde') should return 'fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

Here is my code, it's **only** returning the very first missing letter :

```
function findMissing(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   
    var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
               
    if (code !== str.charCodeAt(0) + i) {
     
      return String.fromCharCode(code - 1);
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
    
findMissing("abce");
   //returns 'd'
```

Comment: return statement in a foor loop causes the loop to exit

Comment: I suggest using a list `missing`, initially empty, and writing `missing.push(String.fromCharCode(code -1));` instead of `return String.fromCharCode(code - 1);`

Comment: By your definition, why does the scenario `findMissing('abcde')` return `efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` (inclusive of `e`)?

Comment: @esqew Sorry I mistyped it, now it's fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is much simpler

```
const findMissing = (str) => {
  let missing = '';
  for (let s of 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') {
    if (str.indexOf(s) === -1) missing += s;
  }
  return missing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `return` in a for loop causes the loop to break.
Use an array to fill, and then return the array

```
function findMissing(str) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
           
        if (code !== str.charCodeAt(0) + i) {
 
            array.push(String.fromCharCode(code - 1));
        }
    }
    return array;
}


myArray = findMissing("abce");
```

Comment: It still only returns "d"?

Comment: Unfortunately yes

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution possible, as a bonus.

```js
const a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const r = (s) => a.replace(/\w/g, (m) => s.includes(m) ? '' : m);

console.log(r('abcd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function findMissing(str) {
    let allLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
    let inputLetters = str.split('');
    for (let i = 0; i < inputLetters.length; i++) {
        let index = allLetters.indexOf(inputLetters[i]);
        if(index != -1) allLetters.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return allLetters.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following you original code approach with few small changes :

```
function findMissing(str) {
  let alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   
    var char = str.charAt(i);

    if (alphabet.indexOf(char)!==-1) {
      alphabet=alphabet.replace(char,'');
    }
  }

  return alphabet;
}

console.log(findMissing("abce"));
```